# Amazon S3 Save Response Stream

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to load a .gz file out of a bucket. 
Connection and authentication work finde, I even do get a file, but the problem is, the file is a lot bigger then the file should be. it is, original size, 155MB within the bucket but when it comes onto my hard disk it gets up to about 288MB

here is the function code:

```
        public bool SaveBucketToFile(string Filename)
    {
        //Response check into file
        using (StreamReader StRead = new StreamReader(_ObjResponse.ResponseStream))
        {
            string TempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();

            StreamWriter StWrite = new StreamWriter(TempFile, false);

            StWrite.Write(StRead.ReadToEnd());

            StWrite.Close();
            StRead.Close();

            // Move to real destination 
            if (File.Exists(Filename))
            {
                File.Delete(Filename);
            }
            File.Move(TempFile, Filename);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

the download and filling of _ObjResponse is made over usage of the AmazonS3 Client from their SDK. I am using a proxy but the same code on a different machine without proxy brings back the same result.

Any hints what to do here? the object request is simple:

```
            _ObjRequest = new GetObjectRequest
                                      {
                                          BucketName = BucketName,
                                          Key = Key
                                      };
```

glad for any help...

Answer (score 1):

for everyone to stumble upon this.

I needed to first save the stream via bufferedStream into a memorystream.

the code looks like this:

```
                MemoryStream MemStream = new MemoryStream();
            BufferedStream Stream2 = new BufferedStream(_ObjResponse.ResponseStream);
            byte[] Buffer = new byte[0x2000];
            int Count;
            while ((Count = Stream2.Read(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                MemStream.Write(Buffer, 0, Count);
            }
            // Pfad auslesen
            string TempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
            //Stream zum Tempfile öffnen
            FileStream Newfile = new FileStream(TempFile,FileMode.Create);

            //Stream wieder auf Position 0 ziehen
            MemStream.Position = 0;
            // in Tempdatei speichern
            MemStream.CopyTo(Newfile);
            Newfile.Close();
            // Endgültigen Speicherpunkt prüfen und Tempdatei dorthin schieben
            if (File.Exists(Filename))
            {
                File.Delete(Filename);
            }
            File.Move(TempFile, Filename);
```

I found this somewhere here: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/186132/Beginning-with-Amazon-S under the Caption "Get a file from Amazon S3"